# Getting null in getTag() used with editText

Tags: android, null, android-view

I'm working on an app created for the purpose of auditing the hotels. I have already asked a couple questions regarding this. Help needed again.

This is a method used to create layout programatically based on the type of 'question' extracted from JSON:

```
 public void getQuestion(String page) {

        .
        .
        .


         for (int i = 0; i < questionList.size(); i++) {
                        LL.setId(i);


                        if (questionList.get(i).categoryName.equalsIgnoreCase("general")) {

                            TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                            row.setId(i);
                            row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                            //LinearLayout generalLayout = new LinearLayout(AuditForm.this,)
                            if (questionList.get(i).questionType.equalsIgnoreCase("editText")) {

                                TextView txtLable = new TextView(getActivity());
                                txtLable.setId(i);
                                txtLable.setHeight(110);
                                txtLable.setPadding(0, 8, 0, 0);
                                txtLable.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                txtLable.setText(questionList.get(i).questionText);
                                txtLable.setTag(questionList.get(i).questId);


                                if (questionList.get(i).questionText.equalsIgnoreCase("Date of inspection(dd-mm-yyyy)")) {
                                    edtdateBox = new EditText(getActivity());
                                    edtdateBox.setHeight(70);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    edtdateBox.setId(edtId_1);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 3)                                               edtdateBox.setTag(questionList.get(i).questionText);

                                    edtdateBox.setClickable(true);
                                    edtdateBox.setKeyListener(null);

                                    View v =new View(getActivity());
                                    v.setMinimumHeight(70);
                                    v.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    v.setId(edtId*1000);

                                    edtdateBox.setText(inspctDate);

                                    LL.addView(txtLable);
                                    LL.addView(edtdateBox);
                                    LL.addView(v);   

                                }

                                else if (questionList.get(i).questionText.equalsIgnoreCase("This Audit Is For City:")) {

                                    edtdateBox = new EditText(getActivity());
                                    edtdateBox.setHeight(70);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    edtdateBox.setId(edtId_1);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 3);
                                    edtdateBox.setText(PropertySelectionPage.selectedCity);
                                    edtdateBox.setTag(questionList.get(i).questionText);

                                    edtdateBox.setClickable(true);
                                    edtdateBox.setKeyListener(null);

                                    View v =new View(getActivity());
                                    v.setMinimumHeight(70);
                                    v.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    v.setId(edtId*1000);

                                    LL.addView(txtLable);
                                    LL.addView(edtdateBox);
                                   LL.addView(v);






                                } else if (questionList.get(i).questionText.equalsIgnoreCase("This Audit Is For Property:")) {
                                    edtdateBox = new EditText(getActivity());
                                    edtdateBox.setHeight(70);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    edtdateBox.setId(edtId_1);
                                    edtdateBox.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 3);
                                    edtdateBox.setText(PropertySelectionPage.selectedProperty);
                                    edtdateBox.setTag(questionList.get(i).questionText);

                                    edtdateBox.setClickable(true);
                                    edtdateBox.setKeyListener(null);

                                    View v =new View(getActivity());
                                    v.setMinimumHeight(70);
                                    v.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    v.setId(edtId*1000);


                                    LL.addView(txtLable);
                                    LL.addView(edtdateBox);
                                    LL.addView(v);


                                }


                             else if (questionList.get(i).questionText.equalsIgnoreCase("Property Address:")) {
                                edtdateBox = new EditText(getActivity());
                                edtdateBox.setHeight(70);
                                edtdateBox.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                edtdateBox.setId(edtId_1);
                                edtdateBox.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 3);
                                edtdateBox.setText(PropertySelectionPage.propAddress);
                                    edtdateBox.setTag(questionList.get(i).questionText);

                                    edtdateBox.setClickable(true);
                                edtdateBox.setKeyListener(null);

                                View v =new View(getActivity());
                                v.setMinimumHeight(70);
                                v.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                v.setId(edtId*1000);


                                LL.addView(txtLable);
                                LL.addView(edtdateBox);
                                LL.addView(v);


                            }

                                 else {
                                    EditText edtBox = new EditText(getActivity());
                                    edtBox.setHeight(70);
                                    edtBox.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    edtBox.setId(edtId);
                                    edtBox.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 3);
                                    edtBox.setTag(questionList.get(i).questionText);

                                    View v =new View(getActivity());
                                    v.setMinimumHeight(70);
                                    v.setPadding(2, 5, 3, 3);
                                    v.setId(edtId*1000);

                                    LL.addView(txtLable);
                                    LL.addView(edtBox);
                                   LL.addView(v);
                                    edtId++;
                                }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        //Similar code for other types of questions (like spinner, ratingBar etc.)
    }
```

The views in above method are used in this method:

```
  private void loopQuestions(ViewGroup parent) {

        JSONArray ansArry = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject params;
        String inspectedDate = "", InspectedBy = "" , prop_city = "", prop_Name = "" ;
      //  Property p = null;
    try {

        //loop1
        Log.e("Total Child", parent.getChildCount() + "");
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            String header =""; // getHeader(i);
            if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
                //Support for linearlayout
                ViewGroup llchild = (LinearLayout) child;


                //loop 2
                for (int j = 0; j < llchild.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    View subChild = llchild.getChildAt(j);


                    params = new JSONObject();
                    if (subChild instanceof EditText) {
                        nosOfQustion++;
                        EditText edtText = (EditText) subChild;


                 //USING THE BELOW LINE PREVENTS CRASHING OF APP
                        if   (edtText.getTag() == null){ break;}
                        if (edtText.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Inspected By")) {
                            InspectedBy = getText(edtText.getText().toString().trim());
                        } else {
                            params.put("Question", edtText.getTag() + "");
                            params.put("Answer", getText(edtText.getText().toString()));
                            params.put("Category", header);
                            ansArry.put(params);
                        }
```

.
.
.

I have indicated in the comment in above method that using                             `"if (edtText.getTag() == null){ break;}" prevents crashing of app. But the problem is that the value of 'edtTxt' is still null, because of which I'm not able to do tasks like saving the audit.

Also, the above methods are in a fragment created to serve as a Tab in TabLayout . I have called the first method (getQuestion()) in the onViewCreated() method. Tried to call it in onCreateView(), but got NullPointerException on doing that.

Please help!

Comment: your EditText is returning null or the getTag() method?

Comment: "edtText.getTag()" is returning null.

Comment: And what's your getText() method returning?

Comment: It looks like you are setting the tag on every `EditText` you create, so do some debugging to figure out if that's true, and it any of those `questionList.get(i).questionText` fields is null.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get text from edittext text then use below code.

```
edtText.getText().toString();
```

For compare value of edittext use below code.

```
String edtText = edtAns.getText().toString();

if (edtText.isEmpty()) {

     Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Please enter correct value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the text of EditText box. I'm trying to get string stored as 'tag' in the EditText box using setTag(). This tag is the question associated with the answer the user types in the EditText box.